# Ember.js app, Parse throws 404 for any path but root

Tags: ember.js, parse-platform

I have an ember app that is served by Parse hosting, and for the most part it's working great if the user starts at the root URL (for which Parse serves up the public/index.html file). However, if a user loads the page at any path, say, /about, Parse will look for a public/about.html file, which doesn't exist (ember serves everything from the index.html file). Parse throws a 404 for any path but the root. How do I get around this?

I have a mini Express app setup, perhaps I could catch all routes and render the index.html file that's in the public folder? The docs only talk about rendering templates from the cloud/views folder (not the public folder, which is where the index.html file is).

Update / Clarification:

This is not an issue with Ember itself (the app works fine on my local machine). The issue is with Parse. When a URL, parseapp.com/entries, is loaded, parse looks for a file in the cloud/public folder called entries.html. There is no such file, this app is an ember app, and ember is loaded from the index.html file. Thus, for every path, I need parse to load the public/index.html file (and then ember routing will take care of the rest).

Comment: I have encounter this exact problem, and here is the approach that i took. Embers has its own routing mechanism. And mixing them will never be pretty. So 2 options here: 1/ if your about page is dynamic content, then render it with ember technique (handlesbar, route), and you might as well use controller since content will be changing over time. 2./ if your content is static and will not likely be changing then use you express and set hard link url via window.location.

Comment: The /about was just an example path, this occurs for any path that's not the root "/" path. The issue is that my ember app never gets hit, because Parse hosting tries to serve a file that doesn't exist. If the path is /posts, Parse will try and serve "cloud/public/posts.html", which does not exist. Parse then displays a 404 to the user, never having loaded the ember app (that's initialized in index.html).

Comment: Have you enabled `location: 'history'` in your `Router`?  By default, it should be using a hash URL

Comment: @SteveH. I've updated my question with some more information. This isn't an issue with ember. Ember isn't even being hit in this case, Parse 404's before the ember app is loaded.

Comment: @Marc, do you understand what I am asking?  Because normally by using a hash, the URL should be `parseapp.com/#/entries`.  This should load the same index file.  Only if you configure the Router with `location: 'history'` will the URL `parseapp.com/entries` be used.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you're saying now. I could give it a go with hashes. Ideally I'd like to use regular URLs, but if that's not possible so be it. Any ideas to fix it on parse's end?

Comment: Was there any resolution to this?