# Hosting Ember-CLI app on Parse.com

Tags: ember.js, parse-platform, hosting, ember-cli

This is a follow-up question to [Ember.js app, Parse throws 404 for any path but root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107973/ember-js-app-parse-throws-404-for-any-path-but-root):

I have built an Ember-CLI app that I now want to host on Parse.com.

I can't figure out how to actually run the app server on Parse.  I confess I don't understand how to serve an Ember-CLI in production from any server.

Do I run "ember server" on Parse somehow or do I need to make my own Express server for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run parse new in some temp folder to create the correct config files for your existing parse app
2. Edit .ember-cli file and add `"output-path" : "dist/public"` to deploy your code to `dist/public`
3. Copy the folders `code` and `config` from your temp folder in step 1 to `dist/code` and `dist/config`
4. In a terminal window `cd dist` and `parse deploy`
5. Edit `environment.js` in your ember config folder and change `locationType` to `hash`

Comment: Have you tried navigating to any URL other than the root one for your app?

Comment: We should potentially add how to redirect all Parse URLs to index.html to your answer

Comment: Step 5 takes care of that.  Using hash urls works with parse pretty well

Comment: By changing locationType to hash your routes change from /login to /#/login that makes parse happy and ember can care less.